# Meaning of `export PATH=…` in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell, path

I'm using a mac for some years now and as I'm currently learning ruby on rails, I felt like I should learn more about the system I'm using. I took a look at the `~/.bash_profile`, it looks like this

```
PATH="/Users/nikolajandersen/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$

# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

As there are two identical `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` lines, I tried to delete the one. As a result, commands like nano and ls didn't work anymore. I reverted the change but I don't understand why it has to stated two times.

Another question is: why does it sometimes $PATH and sometimes just PATH without the $?
Why does `-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` stand in [[ ]] braces? And what does `export PATH` do?

**Update** This is the output of `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Users/nikolajandersen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/nikolajandersen/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/bin:/Users/nikolajandersen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin:/Users/nikolajandersen/.rvm/bin:/Users/nikolajandersen/.apportable/SDK/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

It seems like you were right with the newline. I deleted the line again and made sure that there is a blank line in the end. Now the commands are still working.

Comment: Please don't combine multiple questions in a single post. The issue with `PATH` vs `$PATH` is explained [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-5.html), and [`[[ ]]`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS) is a test operator, it basically means `if`. The duplicate exports should have no effect, that's weird, I recommend you focus on that one and make you question about the `export`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the multiple questions and thanks for the answers.

Comment: Welcome to the bright side! Before we google, we like to read manuals, called man pages. Bash's man page (man bash) can answer all your questions.

Comment: @Bananguin in the OP's defense, `man bash` is 5465 lines long, not the easiest of reads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PATH` before `=` is a variable name and the combination tells `bash` to store the stuff behind the `=` in the variable.
The `$PATH` is the value of the variable PATH up until then.

The combination `PATH="some_path_to_stuff:$PATH"` *extends* the PATH variable. In `bash` this is a colon (`:`) separated list.

---

Regarding the double addition of `/usr/local/bin`, I can only guess that the second version has no newline after it (and is at the end of the file). In principle this should give you a PATH which starts with `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:....`. You can check that with

```
echo $PATH
```

And if there is only one time `/usr/local/bin` then do:

```
echo "" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

and login  an try to print `$PATH` again.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I updated my question with the echo $PATH output. It looks a little weird.